# gitlab can not change gitlab url ,i edit config,yml , gitlab.yml

Tags: macos, docker, gitlab

i running a default gitlab container .. all is ok ,then  i want to change gitlab url to my domain ... there is some strange issue.

i used Mac osx os.

so . i used

```
boot2docker ssh

#entry my vm then

sudo nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid

#entry my container ..(PID is ok )


vi /home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml

#then edit

"
gitlab:

   host: git.qingluan.com
      ...
"

vi /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml

#edit

"
gitlab_url: "http://git.qingluan.com/"

"
vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

#edit


"
server_name git.qingluan.com
"
```

then i ctrl-d  to exit

> docker restart container_id
>   then

...
but gitlab url is not change ... localhost as same as old ...

when i use  `entry my container ..(PID is ok )`  after entry    ry  ..

/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml 
 is back to old

/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml is also back to old ...

/etc/nginx/.../default  is change ok!!!!!!!!!

why ?.... 
please help me ... 
the best is to complain why take place this strange thing ...
                                                                ---thank you

Comment: Which gitlab image do you use? sameersbn/gitlab maybe?

Comment: yes  version is latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing config files in running container try running it with environment variables YOUR_SERVER_FQDN and GITLAB_HOST, like this:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -e="YOUR_SERVER_FQDN=yourdomain.com" -e="GITLAB_HOST=yourdomain.com" sameersbn/gitlab
```

You can check how these variables are used in configuration files templates:

https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=GITLAB_HOST